CKEditor en React - Sube imágenes correctamente, pero el editor alerta que no
La imagen es enviada correctamente al servidor, pero por alguna razón CKEditor no la reconoce.
Tengo el componente PostEditor donde configuro CKEditor:
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

const PostEditor = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  return (
    <CKEditor
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      config={{
        ckfinder: {
          uploadUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/image/list/",
        },
        upload: {
          dataType: "multipart", 
        },
      }}
      data={value}
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        // console.log(event);
        // console.log(editor);
        console.log(data);
        onChange(data);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default PostEditor;

Este es el error:

No se ve cuando selecciono la imagen desde el explorador.
Si alguien sabe algo, le agradecería. Es la primera vez que uso CKeditor.

Pues por aqui eres el primero que pregunta por ckeditor, el error dice que no la puede cargar cannot upload, puede que te este faltando llamar a alguna propiedad en el componente CKeditor, también hay que revisar con que tipo de imagenes se puede trabajar en el

Sí, dice cannot upload, pero como se muestra en el gif, sí se sube. No muestra ningún error en consola y ya probé distintos formatos de imagen.

Ok, entonces ya pudiste subir sin problema los formatos jpeg, png... pero el formato gif no

sí, puedo subir todos los formatos, solamente que no los carga el mismo CKEditor y lanza ese error no se por qué

si te fijas, la imagen se sube automáticamente al tratar de ingresarla al post, comportamiento que se espera, y se agrega correctamente como se muestra en la api, sin embargo, no la reconoce como si se hubiera subido la imagen

Ya configuraste los domains de las imagenes en el archivo next.config.js?

no estoy desarrollando en next, sino en django, y las imágenes están siendo subidas al servidor correctamente desde el front mediante CKEditor, pero el mismo editor, después de que se suba la imagen, me da el error de que no se ha subido.

Ya veo, mi error por no revisar las etiquetas, espero ver si puedo darme tiempo esta semana en revisar el CKeditor, puede que orto colega de la comunidad S.O. en Español nos de una mano también
